# Convert Associative Array in PHP and insert it to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, associative-array

I have a cart session stored in **$_SESSION['cart']** that store the book's data (book_name, book_image, book_price, etc) if the user click 'buy'. I want to display the ***book_name* only** using this code :

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
    echo implode(', ', $key);
}
```

but it return into *invalid arguments passed*. I know that `$key` variable store the book name, and the `$key` variable store how much the book's amount.
What i want is display the items into one string like this

> book1, book2, book3

and then store it into one table row in my database like this :

> ```
>      book_name     | total_price | etc..
> ```
>
> ----------------------------+-------------+------
>
> book1, book2, book3     |   120000   | ....

So the conclusion of my problems above is :

1. How to convert the book_name that is an associative array into one string?
2. Then how to store the book_name (that has been 'converted' to one string) into one table row?

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well `$key` would have to be an array in order to be imploded, so if you have stored these names as keys (strings) then you can echo the keys or store all the keys into an array and implode that array with commas.

Comment: You may be able to just use `implode(', ', array_keys($_SESSION['cart']));`

Comment: Thanks @Rasclatt, now i'm able to convert the $_SESSION['cart'] that is an associative array into one string. Thank you :D