# Get record value from database and implode it

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, associative-array

According to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205252/convert-associative-array-in-php-and-insert-it-to-database), i'm able to convert an associative array to a single string using implode. Now, from the cart session (**$_SESSION['cart']**) i want to get the book's image(s) name (which is an associative array) and convert it into a single string. Here is my code :

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=> $value) {
    $sql    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name='$key'"); //take image name from table product with book_name=$key

    $images = array();
    while ($product_image= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $images[] = $product_image['book_image'];
    }

    echo implode(', ', $images);
}
```

What i want to see from my code above is :

> book1_image, book2_image, book3_image

But it return into this :

> book1_imagebook2_imagebook3_image

I think the implode method i write isn't working. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Can anyone help me again? Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine https://3v4l.org/iEolv Find error somewhere else.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code (using mysql_* which is obsolete and will be going away altogether soon, using untrusted input to build a query string, executing multiple SQL queries in a loop when a single query can fetch all items in one go, etc),

Comment: Were they correctly stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, of course they were correctly stored, because all the table record printed correctly. What's wrong here are i must place the implode after the foreach, and declare the images variable before the foreach. Anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in wrong `echo` position.

```
// define images as empty array before you loop
$images = array();   

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=> $value) {
    $sql    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name='$key'"); //take image name from table product with book_name=$key

    while ($product_image= mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $images[] = $product_image['book_image'];
    }
}

// echo after you check all items
echo implode(', ', $images);
```

And your bunch of queries can be replaced with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')
```

And last but not least - `mysql` extension **must be avoided**, as it's already removed from php.

Comment: if i write the echo after the foreach, it will display the last item stored in the cart session

Comment: Because you set `$images` to empty array every iteration. Check my code again.

Comment: Ah, i see. So i write the echo and my images variable in the wrong place, thanks man! :D